# Unix timestamp is not getting converted correctly to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, ios4, unix-timestamp

I have parsed an api which returns a unixtimestamp for last updated value. I am trying to convert it into NSDate. The code is below

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[[feedCount objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"firstitemmsec"] intValue]];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

When I NSLog the date, I am getting date like this:

```
2038-01-19 03:14:07 +0000
```

The above date is obviously wrong

What is the mistake in the above code?

EDIT: my unixtimestamp is

```
"firstitemmsec":"1264396813500"
```

This value is obviously bigger for int. So how best can I handle this situation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unix timestamps are in seconds, the value you have looks like a number of *milliseconds* since 1st January 1970.  If you divide by 1000, you get 1264396813, which according to [this converter](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) is:

```
Mon, 25 Jan 2010 05:20:13 GMT
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the value of `[[[feedCount objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"firstitemmsec"] intValue]`--odds seem good that it's not a valid UNIX timestamp (okay, it is since any `int` value is on iOS, but obviously it's not the *right* value.)

Comment: I have my unixtimestamp as "1264396813500". But converting to int will obviously destroy the value. What is the best solution for this?

Comment: That's well out of the range of UNIX timestamps, i.e. it's not a valid `time_t` value. What's the actual date/time it's supposed to represent?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's another to do. Erase the "500" at the end of your number wich is an error code from the server and you have a right unix time ;)

There was probably an error or a bug on your server... ???